# Alinhar valores preenchidos por colunas usando case when no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

Como eu poderia alinhar os valores nessa consulta do SQL por coluna, são 2 perguntas  possíveis para cada pergunta numa lista de vários usuários que responderam a primeira e a segunda pergunta:

- pergunta um?
  resposta um
- pergunta dois?
  resposta dois

Esse é o SQL de extração dessas respostas hoje:

```
SELECT 
         evuser.usr_id as user_id,        
                (case when (quest.evl_id = 4 and quest.evq_id = 9) then evq_question_name end) as pergunta1,  
                (case when (quest.evl_id = 4 and quest.evq_id = 10) then evq_question_name end) as pergunta2,  
                (case when eua.evq_id = 9 then eua_answer end) as resposta1,
                (case when eua.evq_id = 10 then eua_answer end) as resposta2    
        from evaluation_user_answers eua
        left join evaluation_user_applied evuser
            on eua.eua_id = evuser.eua_id
        left join evaluation_questions quest
            on quest.evq_id = eua.evq_id    
        where 
            eua.evq_id in (9, 10) and quest.evl_id=4;
```

**Tabelas:**

```
CREATE TABLE `evaluation_questions` (
  `evq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evl_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `evq_question_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evl_type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evl_order` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evl_max_pontuation` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evl_required` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evl_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `evl_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`evq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `evaluation_user_applied` (
  `eua_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eua_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eua_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `eua_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eua_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `evaluation_user_answers` (
  `eua_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `evq_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eua_answer` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eua_created` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `eua_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Veja que se eu pegar o grupo 9 ele me traz assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu colocar o grupo 10, assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas seu eu juntar os dois, ta vindo com nulo, queria deixar tudo alinhado nas colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se nesse exemplo criado seria uma resposta válida pra sua pergunta, se entendi bem, poderia resolver sem utilizar o `CASE WHEN`. Veja o exemplo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/948113/11.

Comment: Utilizando `CASE WHEN`, poderia ficar dessa forma http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/948113/14?